# UIScrollView disables all other user interaction?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uialertview

I have an issue with a UIScrollView. I want to invoke a view with a navigation controller. My code has a method to detect tap gestures and thus hide or reveal the navigation bar and the toolbar.

I also have a method that when the user presses a button, a UIAlertView is displayed. These work fine when the scroll view is hidden (I commented the code out), however when I add the view, the gesture recognition and the UIAlertView don't seem to work? Buttons on the navigation bar however do work...

any ideas on how to enable them? Below is my code to call the ScrollView:

```
  scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,     self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger viewCount = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
        [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
        [filterViewOverlay release];
    }
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    [scroll release];
```

Cheers in advance!

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Scrollview is behind all other IBOutlets, and make sure user interaction is enabled.

Comment: How would you put the the scrollView behind the navigation bar? Isn't the nav bar linked to the nab controller which the scrollView loads from? Also the alert views are called after the scrollView after a button is pressed (which works) but still are not displayed so the scrollView (I am assuming) is already behind that. As for the IBOutlets, there are none because they are all pragmatically coded onto the navigation bar/toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the scroll view's `delaysContentTouches` property. The default value is YES, which means that the scroll view won't forward touch events until it decides whether the touch is part of a gesture that it recognizes, such as scrolling or zooming.

Comment: I used the code scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO; but still nothing works. I am trying to use just a single tap as the gesture.